# How can i add a parameter to specific toast function?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

its a little weird question and so simple but i'm stucked! i have my custom toast so when i call it i want to call the function like this for example showToast("text on toast") i tried to do it but it's not showing when i click the button and this is my code

```
private void customToast(String Content) {

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        View customToastroot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_toast, null);
        Toast customToast = new Toast(context);

        TextView toastText = findViewById(R.id.toast_text);

        Content = "";

        toastText.setText(Content);

        customToast.setView(customToastroot);
        customToast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        customToast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
        customToast.show();

    }
```

and this is my button called by JavaScriptInterface its working fine but after adding (String Content) toast not showing!

```
    public class WebViewJavaScriptInterface{

        private Context context;

        WebViewJavaScriptInterface(Context context){

            this.context = context;

        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void showToast() {

            customToast("Thanks Allah");

        }

        public Context getContext() {
            return context;
        }

        public void setContext(Context context) {

            this.context = context;

        }

    }
```

this is my activity_toast.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/toast"
        android:alpha="0.80"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toast_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="this is the TextVie"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_semibold"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Setting `Content = "";` might be your issue.

Comment: @computercarguy  I removed but nothing showed, i added some information about my question. thanks

Comment: add activity_toast layout code , it will help

Comment: @EmadSeliem i added it

Comment: Please check below code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void customToast(String Content) {

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View customToastroot = inflater.inflate(R.layout. activity_toast, null);
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, Content, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setView(customToastroot);
        TextView text =  customToastroot.findViewById(R.id.toast_text);
        /*Here you can do anything with above textview like text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));*/
        text.setText(Content);
        toast.show();
    }
```

Comment: thanks sir, you saved my day. it's working perfectly!